# Is the file loaded in RAM when i open the file in write mode?

Tags: c, file, file-handling

Suppose I have a empty file. Now the file is opened (let's assume i am using c language)
Then my question is:-

Is the file loaded in RAM?

What happens if i write data in the file whose size is greater than size of RAM? Is the data successfully written in the file or not( since the size of data is greater than RAM) ?

Comment: Depends on the underlying OS works. On your common OSs it is most likely not.

Comment: This depends on the operating system but usually the file is not loaded in advance, especially in its entirety to the memory.

Comment: If I recall correctly, on most operating systems, the changes are buffered in RAM until you call fflush(). (So no the ENTIRE file isn't loaded into RAM as that would be unnecessary)

Comment: Just curious about how you think an *empty* file would be loaded into RAM. Would that involve emptying the RAM?

Comment: @Adrian Mole  when the file is opened in RAM only then writing operation can be done. This is my thought. So i mentioned about the emptiness of file..

Comment: General-purpose operating systems commonly keep a cache of blocks from disk—any block that has just been used, for reading or writing, is kept for the moment. This is because there is no benefit to discarding data. It might be used again, in which case it is good to have it alreadyin memory instead of reading it from disk again. When the system needs memory for other purposes and there is no free memory, it will choose which data to discard then, from data that has been kept for convenience but is not truly needed. The criteria for that vary with the operating system and circumstances.

Comment: This is implementation dependent. Dont rely on it to be loaded to ram. If a writing operation fails, (most) write functions return some sort of error code.

Comment: @lulle i know the function will return some sort of error. But, is there any chance that error will occur due to exceeding the RAM size. ?

Comment: Let's get this away from the realm of abstract speculation to something more focused. If you have a code example and some specific OS in mind, we can examine your scenario more reliably.

Comment: @dratenik  Sorry, i haven't written any code for this i just want to know the concept...

Comment: "Can write to a file fail because the file is larger than RAM?" technically yes, if the file resides on a ramdisk. Were you looking for this answer? Probably not.

Comment: Is there a way you could explore this for yourself? Just write a program that writes a sufficiently large file and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if i write data in the file whose size is greater than size of RAM?

The size of a file is not limited by C to the RAM memory space available.

> Is the file loaded in RAM?

Usually a portion is loaded in RAM on a as needed basis, but that is an implementation detail and should not be expected to limit file size.

> Is the file loaded in RAM when i open the file in write mode?

Usually not,  but that is an implementation detail and should not be expected to limit file size.

> Is the data successfully written in the file or not( since the size of data is greater than RAM) ?

Again the size of RAM is not a usual concern when writing to a file.  I/O errors may be detected per each I/O command like from the return value of `fprintf()`.   Success in final  writing data to a file is reported on `fclose()`.  Before that, that data may be partially written.  Research `fflush()` to help insure select partial data is written before `fclose()`.